# Run through canvas pixels and find x, y, position for every white pixel

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I have a canvas of which i have drawn some white text on to.

I then get the canvas image data and run through each pixel checking if its white:

```
  var pixelData = 
  this.ctx.getImageData(0,0,this.ctx.canvas.width,this.ctx.canvas.height);


    for(var i = 0; i < pixelData.data.length;i+=4) //run through pixels
        if(pixelData.data[i] == 255 && pixelData.data[i+1] == 255 && pixelData.data[i+2] == 255) //is white?
            this.possiblePxs.push(i);
```

I read somewhere that "getImageData" returns a one dimensional array where the first element is is the red value of the first pixel, second is blue third is green and fourth is alpha

and so i increment the loop by 4 each iteration.

if a white pixel is found i store it in the "possiblePxs" array.

Later in my code i need to select one of these pixels and draw something at its location 
and so first i create a new random index between 0 and the length of "possiblePxs":

```
var randomPx = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.possiblePxs.length)
```

Then, in order to get the x location i just take the result of the value of possiblePxs at that random index modulus the canvas height:

```
var randomX = this.possiblePxs[randomPx] % this.ctx.canvas.height
```

and i can then get the y location by subtracting randomX from the value of possiblePxs at the random index and divide it by the height of the canvas again:

```
var randomY = (this.possiblePxs[randomPx] - randomX ) / this.ctx.canvas.height;
```

However this doesn't seem to be working, when i then draw a rect at the location its nowhere near any of the white pixels on the canvas?

I must have messed up the math of either the loop or the finding x, y part. I was hoping maybe one of you guys could tell me what i did wrong and how to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push the value of `i`, you should divide `i` by 4:

```
this.possiblePxs.push(i/4);
```

And the extraction of the X coordinate should be modulo the *width* not the height of the canvas:

```
var randomX = this.possiblePxs[randomPx] % this.ctx.canvas.width;
```

Similarly for the Y coordinate:

```
var randomY = (this.possiblePxs[randomPx] - randomX ) / this.ctx.canvas.width;
```